# How to parse property/value pairs from a CSS text

Tags: javascript, css, regex

How can I extract all property/value pairs present in a CSS text

**Example** :
From this CSS

```
var cssText = "background-image:url(\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8\"); color:green; content:'(test)'";
```

I have to extract key/value pairs :

```
background-image =>  url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8")
color => green
content => "(test)"
```

I tried `cssText.split(';')`, but it doesn't work because the base64 code contains a `;`

Comment: Use a CSS parser, not regex.  CSS is not a regular language.

Comment: OK, which CSS parser can I use for that ? please
Otherwise, a css text has always a certain structure, I think it is possible to parse it using a Regex ... that I do not master ^^

Comment: Google can help you find a good parser.  Just google "css parser c#"

Comment: Is it possible to use regex for this?  Maybe.  But you're going to keep coming across input that breaks your regex, and it'll become so heinously complex that in a few months you'll have no idea how it works or how to fix its latest defect.  Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
let element = document.createElement("div");

element.style = "background-image: url(\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8\"); color:green; content:'(test)'";

console.log([...element.style]);
for (name of element.style) console.log(name, ":", element.style[name]);
```

Output:

```
["background-image", "color", "content"]

background-image : url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8")
color : green
content : "(test)"
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vb9q1sot/

Tested on the current Google Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. Testing on browser compatibility needed such as for MS Edge or Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a space after each ; but not in the base64, then just add the space to the split argument.

```
cssText.split('; ')
```

Comment: There is not always a space after each ";"

Answer (score 0):

In some cases we are not in the context of an html **document**, here a function based on **Regex** to extract css rules :

```
var parseCssRules = function (cssText) {
    var tokenizer = /\s*([a-z\-]+)\s*:\s*((?:[^;]*url\(.*?\)[^;]*|[^;]*)*)\s*(?:;|$)/gi,
    obj = {},
    token;
    while ( (token=tokenizer.exec(cssText)) ) {
       obj[token[1].toLowerCase()] = token[2];
    }
   return obj;
};
```